# Wordpress unexpected return from get_categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

### TL;DR

Wordpress **get_categories** function doesn't return an **Array** if a category is not assigned to a post. Check at the end how to replicate this.

### Context

**Test Environment**

**Wordpress**: 5.4.2 and 5.1.1

**PHP**: 7.4.7

I'm using the following custom endpoint to get all taxonomies from Wordpress, but somehow the type of response I get from `get_categories` isn't always the same.

```
function ca_get_taxonomy() {
  $categories = get_categories(array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
  ));

  $tags = get_tags(array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
  ));

  return array(
    'categories' => $categories,
    'tags' => $tags
  );
}

function custom_api() {
  register_rest_route('custom/v1', 'taxonomy', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
    'callback' => 'ca_get_taxonomy'
  ));
}
```

### Expected Behavior

Wordpress [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/#return) says the `get_categories` function returns an **Array** of objects. So the expected response would be something like this:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "term_id": 3,
      ...
    },
    {
      "term_id": 1,
      ...
    }
  ],
  tags: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

### The Problem

#### Scenario 1 (correct)

If all created categories are assigned to posts the response from `get_categories` is an **Array** which is expected.

#### Scenario 2

This is more tricky (seems to be random), but I think it's true when one of the created categories is not assigned to a post, or one category is not assigned to a post and contains a space (in category name not the category slug). In this case the response from `get_categories` is an **Object** like this:

```
{
  "categories": {
    "0": {
      "term_id": 3,
      ...
    },
    "1":, {
      "term_id": 1,
      ...
    }
  },
  tags: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

### Notes

If I get the **Object** as a response and remove all categories in Wordpress (the default category will apply to all posts) will fix the problem and return again an **Array**. But as soon **Scenario 2** applies the problem returns.

### How to Replicate

1. Download and install a new instance of Wordpress
2. Create a folder inside **wp-content/** named **mu-plugins/**
3. Create a new file named **rest.php** inside that folder and past the code bellow.
4. Visit **yourSiteUrl/wp-json/custom/v1/taxonomy** and you can see an **Array** with one Object inside (the default category)
5. Now, go to Wordpress > Post > Categories and create a new category
6. Visit again **yourSiteUrl/wp-json/custom/v1/taxonomy** and the response will now be an **Object**

**rest.php**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Rest
*/

function ca_taxonomy() {
  $categories = get_categories(array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
  ));

  return $categories;
}

function ca_api() {
  register_rest_route('custom/v1', 'taxonomy', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
    'callback' => 'ca_taxonomy'
  ));
}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'ca_api');

?>
```

Comment: I'm on the same boat :(

Comment: I also had the same issue. The issue got fixed when all the categories had at least one post.